# Max Consecutive Ones in a given array(Leetcode)

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm

I'm trying to find the maximum number of consecutive 1s in the array with O(n) time complexity and not utilizing more than one unit of space.(Other than the variables used for iterating through the array). Here's the code I've come up with, but Leetcode submission shows it's exceeding the time limit. I'm struggling to understand how is it exceeding the time limit because I iterate each element of the array just once and run the logic in the same iteration.

```
public class MaxConsecutive {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println(findMaxConsecutiveOnes(new int[] {0,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1}));
  }

   public static int findMaxConsecutiveOnes(int[] nums) {

     int i=0, j=0, maxLen=0;

     while(j<nums.length) {

         if(nums[j] == 1) {

            i=j; 
            while (true) {
                while (j < nums.length && nums[j] == 1) {
                    j++;
                }

                if( j - i > maxLen) {
                    maxLen = j - i;
                    j++;
                    break;
                }
            }
         }
         else
             j++; 
     }
     return maxLen;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm, I can see three `while` loops

Comment: Yes, why would you need more than one?

Comment: yes indeed there are 3 while loops, but it iterates through the array just once. I agree it's not the best solution but that was the first solution that came to mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
while (true) {
    // ....

    if( j - i > maxLen) {
        maxLen = j - i;
        j++;
        break;
    }

}
```

In this part, you are not breaking the infinity loop unless the current length is maximum than `maxLen`. This loop can be infinite and the program will give you TLE.

I removed the loop and did some modification here:

```
public static int findMaxConsecutiveOnes(int[] nums) {      

     int i=0, j=0, maxLen=0;

     while(j<nums.length) {

         if(nums[j] == 1) {

            i=j;
            while (j + 1 < nums.length && nums[j + 1] == 1) {
                j++;
            }

            if( j - i + 1 > maxLen) {
                maxLen = j - i + 1;
            }
         }

         j++;        
     }

     return maxLen;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Three `while` loops. In my opinion your code is too complex. You just need only **one** loop.

Some simpler solution:

```
public static int findMaxConsecutiveOnes(int[] nums) {
    int maxCount = 0;
    int currentCount = 0;
    for (int number : nums) {
        if (number == 1) {
            currentCount++;
        } else {
            currentCount = 0;
        }
        maxCount = Math.max(maxCount, currentCount);
    }
    return maxCount;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One loop enough. Calling Math.max at min.

```
public static int findMaxConsecutiveOnes(int[] nums) {

 int reset = 0, run=0, maxLen=0;

 for (int i = 0 ; i < nums.length; i++) {

    if ( nums[i] == 1 ) {
        run++;
    } else {
        maxLen = Math.max(maxLen, run);
        run = 0;
    }
 }
 maxLen = Math.max(maxLen, run);

 return maxLen;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class ConsecutiveOne {


    public  static int  Consecutiveones(int[] nums)
    {
        int count=0;
        HashSet Consecutivecount=new HashSet();
       // Object[] obj=new Object[]{};

        for(int i=0;i<nums.length;i++)
        {
            if(nums[i]==1)
            {
                count++;

                if(i==nums.length-1)
                {
                    Consecutivecount.add(count);
                }
            }
            else
            {

                Consecutivecount.add(count);
                count=0;
            }
        }





return (int) Collections.max(Consecutivecount);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int[] arr={1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1};

    int longestCOunt= Consecutiveones(arr);
    System.out.println(longestCOunt);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Solution {
    public int findMaxConsecutiveOnes(int[] nums) {
        int leftEnd =0;
        int maxConCount =0;
        
        while(leftEnd<nums.length){
            if(nums[leftEnd]==0){
                leftEnd++;
            }else{
                int rightEnd = leftEnd;
                while(rightEnd<nums.length && nums[rightEnd]==1){
                    rightEnd++;
                    maxConCount = Math.max(maxConCount,(rightEnd-leftEnd));
                }
                leftEnd = rightEnd++;
            }
        }
        return maxConCount;
    }
}
```